# Invalid Stream header with Stanford nlp library

Tags: java, scala, stanford-nlp

I am working through this [Stanford POS tagger tutorial](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/). I am doing it in Scala but I do not think that this matters.

The line that produces the error is

```
val tagger=new MaxentTagger("/Users/user1/Documents/taggers/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger")
```

and the error is

```
edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0003CBE8
```

The filepath is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the tagger treats the model file path as a classpath-relative resource path, but it also accepts a fully qualified URL:

```
val tagger=new MaxentTagger("file:/Users/user1/Documents/taggers/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem =/

You should put your "`taggers`" folder inside project resources folder, and then your path will look this way:
"`taggers/NAME_OF_MODEL.tagger`" (only "`taggers`" folder should be in the path).

Answer (score 1):

That usually happens when trying to use a model that was trained for a different tagger version. Make sure you are using the models distributed with the 3.3.1 tagger.

I faced the same problem once. Then I realized that the jar version I was using was from 3.3.1 release. And the model was from 3.2.0. I removed the 3.2.0 model files and replaced them with 3.3.1.

Hope this helps.