# Running Stanford corenlp server with French models

Tags: stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I am trying to analyse some French text with the Stanford CoreNLP tool (it's my first time trying to use any StanfordNLP software)

To do so, I have downloaded the v3.6.0 jar and the corresponding [french models](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-french-corenlp-2016-01-14-models.jar).

Then I run the server with:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34782849/4709400), I call the API with:

```
wget --post-data 'Bonjour le monde.' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"parse.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz", "annotators": "parse", "outputFormat": "json"}' -O -
```

but I get the following log + error:

```
 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP  
 Adding annotator tokenize
 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -   Adding annotator ssplit
 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz ... 

 edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 64696374
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.loadModel(ParserGrammar.java:188)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.loadModel(ParserAnnotator.java:212)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.<init>(ParserAnnotator.java:115)
    ...
```

The solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048384/invalid-stream-header-with-stanford-nlp-library) suggest the code and model version differs but I have dowloaded them from the same page (and they both have the same version number in their name) so I am pretty sure they are the same.

Any other hint on what I am doing wrong?

*(I should also mention that I am not a Java expert, so maybe I forgot a stupid step... )*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of readings and unsuccessful tries, I found a way to make it work (for **v3.6.0**).  Here are the details, if they can be of any interest to someone else:

1. Dowload the code and french models from http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download. Unzip the code `.zip` and copy the french model `.jar` to that directory (do not remove the english models, they have different names anyway)
2. cd to that directory and then run the server with:

   ```
   java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
   ```

*(it's a pity that the `-prop` flag doesn't help here)*

3. Call the API repeating the properties listed in the `StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties`:

   ```
   wget --header="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
        --post-data 'Bonjour le monde.' 
        'localhost:9000/?properties={
          "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse", 
          "parse.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz", 
          "pos.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger", 
          "tokenize.language":"fr", 
          "outputFormat": "json"}' 
     -O -
   ```

   which finally gives a 200 response using the French models!

(NB: don't know how to make it work with the UI (same for utf-8 support))

Comment: Can we run CoreNLP using our trained model?

Comment: Yes you can, with the `parse.model` option, and so on for the other annotators.

Comment: Jesus Christ thanks a lot! That would've taken me hours to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

As a potentially useful addition for some, this is what the complete properties file for German looks like:

```
# annotators
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, mwt, pos, ner, depparse

# tokenize
tokenize.language = de
tokenize.postProcessor = edu.stanford.nlp.international.german.process.GermanTokenizerPostProcessor

# mwt
mwt.mappingFile = edu/stanford/nlp/models/mwt/german/german-mwt.tsv

# pos
pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german-ud.tagger

# ner
ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.distsim.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = false
ner.applyFineGrained = false
ner.useSUTime = false

# parse
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/germanSR.beam.ser.gz

# depparse
depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz
```

The complete property files for [Arabic](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-arabic.properties), [Chinese](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties), [French](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties), [German](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties) and [Spanish](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties) can all be found in the [CoreNLP github repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline).