# StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000 This site can’t be reached

Tags: stanford-nlp-server

I'm tring to run the [Stanford CoreNLP server](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html). I'm using the Docker files on this official Stanford list

```
http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/other-languages.html#docker
```

My OS is ubuntu16-4lts. I don't know much about ubuntu, coding, servers, or NLP.

I tried the first one on the list `https://hub.docker.com/r/motiz88/corenlp/` I ran it as is and got this far:

```
steve at ubuntu16-4lts:~$ docker run --name coreNPL --rm -i -t motiz88/corenlp
-- listing properties --
Starting server on port 9000 with timeout of 5000 milliseconds.
StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

But when I goto `http://localhost:9000/` I get: 
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

The second one on the list got similar results.

```
https://github.com/chilland/corenlp-docker
```

Is there something else I'm supposed to do or configure? Is the the *Stanford CoreNLP server* a HTTP server in it's own right, will it serve the link to the localhost:9000 by itself, or does it require the help of an [Apache HTTP Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)?

I've searched stack exchange for "[stanford-nlp] /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000" but could not find one that compares to my situation.

[edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809061/edu-stanford-nlp-io-runtimeioexception-could-not-connect-to-server)

[StanfordCoreNLP differs from StanfordCoreNLPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261247/stanfordcorenlp-differs-from-stanfordcorenlpserver)

Answer (score 1):

The container's port 9000 has to be published to the host. So, the command would be

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 --name coreNPL --rm -i -t motiz88/corenlp
```